# No module named 'torcheval'

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying this on Kaggle:

```
from torcheval.metrics.functional import binary_f1_score
metric = binary_f1_score
```

And i get an Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_28/3857382439.py in <module>
----> 1 from torcheval.metrics.functional import binary_f1_score
      2 metric = binary_f1_score
      3 model_no_CV = unet_1D().to(device)
      4 optimizer =  torch.optim.Adam(unet_1D.parameters(), lr=0.001)
      5 epochs_num = 30

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torcheval'
```

I tried to install the latest version of torch, didn't help
Other torch modules seem to work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install torcheval library in Kaggle. First of all make sure your internet option is enable to use the kernel then you can try this command:

```
!pip install torcheval
```